# Regular Expression definitions, as a rule, what is always true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions

If I have two regular expressions $\sf S$ and $\sf T$, what is always true of these?

options:

1. Both $\sf(SS \mid T)^\ast$ and $\sf(TSS)^\ast$ are subsets of $\sf(TSS\mid STS\mid SST)^\ast$
2. $\sf(TSS)^\ast$ is a subset of $\sf(SS\mid T)^\ast$
3. Neither $\sf(SS\mid T)^\ast$  nor $\sf(TSS)^*$ is a subset of the other.
4. $\sf(SS\mid T)^\ast$ is a subset of $\sf(TSS)^{\ast\ast}$

Here is my issue: I do not think any of these are always true (which is obviously not the case).   (At first I thought 1 but after re-reading my notes, I'm unsure) Can anyone point or hint me in the correct direction WITHOUT telling me which number is correct?

Comment: Please clarify. Is the $+$ in your regexs taken to be the "alternation" operator, expressed also as $\cup$ or $\mid$? It has been edited to the Kleene plus, so check to make sure.

Comment: Indeed, that would give an *entirely* different interpretation of the expressions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure of the difference in how it appears but I did mean + to be meant as alternation.

Comment: How would each be entirely different? I'm unsure how that would be?

Comment: Kleene plus means "one or more repeats of the previous symbol", the alternator means "either this string or that string".  So $(S^+T)$ matches $ST,SST, SSST,$ or so forth, while $(S\mid T)$ matches $S$ or $T$.  Quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes (most redundant because alternation was meant instead of Kleene plus repetition):

- $\sf (S\mid T)$ matches either $\sf S$ or $\sf T$. So $(S\mid T)^\ast$ matches all strings of zero or more length where each character is either $S$ or $T$; which also may be expressed as $(S^\ast T^\ast)^\ast$

---

- $\sf SS^+$ means two or more repeats of $\sf S$
- $\sf SS^+S, SSS^+, S^+SS$ all mean three or more repeats of $\sf S$ .   They are the same pattern.

<s>* An expression is a subset of another if *all of* the strings matched by the former are (*some of* the) strings matched by the later.   This means that, at the very least, you can eliminate expressions that don't start or end in the same symbol.</s>

- That is: $(XY)^\ast \not\subseteq (XYX)^\ast$ because almost all of the former will terminate with a $Y$ (the exception is the empty string), while almost all of the later will terminate with an $X$ (same exception).
- Since the OP meant alternation, this is now not so helpful.

Comment: Not so helpful since the OP meant alternation rather than Kleene plus.